# Pyspark / pyspark kernels not working in jupyter notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Here are installed kernels:

```
 $jupyter-kernelspec list


Available kernels:
  apache_toree_scala    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala
  apache_toree_sql      /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_sql
  pyspark3kernel        /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pyspark3kernel
  pysparkkernel         /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/pysparkkernel
  python3               /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  sparkkernel           /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkkernel
  sparkrkernel          /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/sparkrkernel
```

A new notebook was created but fails with

```
The code failed because of a fatal error:
    Error sending http request and maximum retry encountered..
```

[image]

There is no [error] message in the `jupyter` console

Answer (score 1):

If you use `magicspark` to connect your Jupiter notebook, you should also start Livy which is API service used by magicspark to talk to your Spark cluster.

1. Download `Livy` from [Apache Livy](https://livy.incubator.apache.org/download/) and unzip it
2. Check SPARK_HOME environment is set, if not, set to your Spark installation directory
3. Run Livy server by `<livy_home>/bin/livy-server` in the shell/command line

Now go back to your notebook, you should be able to run spark code in cell.

Comment: Thx for the tip! I am not using a jupyter notebook at this moment but will come back (likely in August) when I do.  Will upvote for now and have in mind to award at that time based on the verification.